# Wordpress - Error with homepage

Tags: wordpress

We have an issue with our wordpress theme http://themeforest.net/item/flowerbomb-multipurpose-responsive-masonry-theme/7799116

The homepage does not appear. another page with errors appears instead.

Can I share the code of the theme and which code should I share so someone can help?

Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: What is the error that you are getting.?

Comment: Enable debugging in `wp-config.php`: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and post the error messages.

Comment: There is no "error message" but a page which is messing words and pictures.

Comment: How can I enable wp-config.php?

Answer (score 0):

Verify:

1. `Include /etc/nginx/mime.types;`

   in nginx.conf (if nginx then only)
2. phpfpm and its php.ini configuration,

   `/etc/php/{version}/fpm/php.ini`